# Quick Wet Goop Recipe

Tags: dont-starve

I need to make some Wet Goop for a mod item. However, any combination of food that I've thrown into the crock pot just gets turned into some good eatin's, like I'm some kind of savant chef.

Is there a quick and easy recipe that even *I* can butcher into Wet Goop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**4 Twigs.** That's it.

A single twig can be used in the various "X-on-a-stick" recipes. If you use more than one twig, then you get Wet Goop. Using 4 twigs to make Wet Goop is usually cheaper than using 2 twigs plus 2 other food items.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Crock_Pot_Recipes#Crock_Pot_Recipes) is a list of all the crock pot recipes in Don't Starve.

Wet Goop is any combination of ingredients that does not produce one of the other valid recipes.

For example:

- 4 twigs
- 4 butterfly wings
- 2 morsels, 2 sticks
- 1 berries, 1 morsel, 1 veg, 1 twig

etc.

Since twigs are regarded as the most efficient filler, 4 twigs is probably your best option, but if for some reason you have a twig shortage, you can use any combination of ingredients that don't fit another valid recipe on that page.